# Multi-item Auctions in Mechanism Design

Tags: auctions, mechanism-design

I'm new to auction theory and only started reading it a few days ago.

**My question is this:** *Is it possible to design efficient auctions of multiple non-identical items? By efficient I mean maximize the social welfare.*

Also, let's say there is only one seller who owns all items and seeks to sell them to multiple bidders who can get at most one item.

I'm a little discouraged as I haven't found a lot of theory papers on this problem. Is it because what I described above is a special of bundling (where bundle sets are singletons)?

I'd appreciate it immensely if you could direct me to a source (paper or book). Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s a large literature on this in both CS and Economics. For economics, a good starting point would be Vijay krishna’s *Auction Theory* book (2009 edition). It has a whole section on multi-object auctions.

For CS, check out some of the papers by Jason Hartline. He may have lecture notes as well. Naom Nisan and others have a book called *algorithmic game theory* where some chapters (if I remember correctly) deal with multi-object auctions.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Tomcat's suggestions, you may also want to check out the literature on matching markets.

Easley and Kleinberg have an [introductory textbook](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/)* on the subject. Chapter 10 covers the basic model of matching markets. Chapter 15 goes over the auction of ad slots as an application.

---

*Easley, David, and Jon Kleinberg (2010) [*Networks, Crowds, and Markets: Reasoning About a Highly Connected World*](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/), Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to have a look at [Krishna's "Auction Theory"](https://www.elsevier.com/books/auction-theory/krishna/978-0-12-374507-1), Chapter 16 "Non-identical items". Regarding your particular multiproduct problem, I would go from [Armstrong's "Multiproduct nonlinear pricing", Econometrica 1996,](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2171924) and see what happens.

While I don't want to discourage you, let me mention that mechanism design with multidimensional types is very, very difficult and can get quite "ugly". See my reply [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/39643/11590). It may not be the kind of problem you want to tackle after you have "only started reading it a few days ago". However, it is quite an important problem and more good research is needed. So I am rooting for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hoping you don't mind but are you aware of any paper studying multi-item, multi-unit auctions in which bidders are only interested in one unit from only one item?

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't think I know such a paper. I would start searching on google.scholar, looking at papers that cite (or are cited) by Thanassoulis, JET 2004, and Carroll, Ecta 2017. Certainly a difficult setting for a mechanism-design setting.

Answer (score 0):

For single unit demand see Maskin and Riley's "Optimal multi-unit Auctions".